# &nbsp suddenly coming all over the aspx. file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suddenly i noticed `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;.....` suddenly showing up in my .aspx file.
Everything seems to be working fine but i have no idea where this is coming from?

These lines appear everywhere inside my validator control where the display="dynamic".

The debugger shows 0 warnings and 0 errors.
What is the cause of this most wierd occurence?

Comment: Check if this is related: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967253

Comment: That would be most wierd since i am already using VS 2010?
And i have no idea what may be thecause of this. And those controls are indeed listed in a multiview control.

Comment: Same issue here.  Seems to happen when I've got conditional code blocks inside my ASPX.  If I find cause I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&nbsp;` specifies a space that browsers will not combine with adjacent spaces into a single space. That is, each `&nbsp;` is always rendered as a separate space.

These can get inserted if you type multiple spaces together as that's the only way to prevent browsers combining multiple spaces into a single space.

Of course, I also notice the VS editor can be a bit quirky at times while updating the markup in response to editing content in design view.

Did you type multiple spaces together? Where are these showing up? Being able to see where they are being inserted may be very helpful in determining why they were inserted.

Comment: They show up in my validation controls with a dynamic display. Those controls are in a multiview contorl.

Comment: Please refer to my other questions and show an example if you'd like help figuring out why they are getting inserted.

Comment: Added one of the validation controls where this is happening. Its exactly the same for all those controls within my multiview. But what  exactly do you mean with multiple spaces? Cause i really have no idea what could cause such a thing (never seen this before).

Comment: Also i think what could be a cause is when i tried to add another view, it refused to show up. Now when i tried removing that, i no longer see these spaces showing up.

Comment: By multiple spaces, I simply mean two or more space characters appearing next to each other. Browsers will combine them into a single space. If you use `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) instead of a regular space ' ', browsers won't do that. It's not possible to say why this happened in your case. My best guess remains that a bunch of spaces got inserted in the design view somehow. As far as something not showing up, perhaps that could be related to your multiview?

Comment: Sorry, 'did you enter them?' is not really a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

These character simple represent "non-breakable" spaces, and I swear they are all intended. See:

[Wikipedia - Non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)